# looping through rows of a mysql table with non sequential index

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this

| index (auto incremented) | data | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | 1 |
| 3 | a2 | 1 |
| 4 | b62 | 3 |
| 9 | m52 | 1 |

and i loop through it with this code

```
for($i=1; $i<= number of rows; $i++){
$query = "SELECT * FROM messagesforinstructor where type='1' and index='$i'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$display=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $display['data'];
}
```

but as you can see that it would fail cause the auto incremented indexes are not sequential.so at i=2 it would fail without making it to i=3.

any idea how to make it select the next index in the table

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use something like `SELECT * FROM messagesforinstructor where type='1' ORDER BY index`?

Comment: As Nigel said... Just select the result set in its entirety and then loop through that with a for/while loop?

Comment: Also, doing it this way, you will have at least as many queries being executed as there are records in the DB (+1 presumably to get the count of records)... Which soon adds up to hundreds or thousands of queries per request.

Comment: @Steven could you illustarte it in a code maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple solution

- Don't use `*` use specified column names
- Use one query to retrieve the entire result set
- Use OOP approach and save yourself having to repeat code (you don't neeed to change the connection but you can:

  ```
   // From...
   $db = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);

   // To...
   $db = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name)
  ```
- I assume that `type` is an integer field; no need to use quotation marks in the query

**Code**

```
// Run the query to select the messages
$sql   = "SELECT data FROM messagesforinstructor WHERE type = 1";
$query =  $db->query($sql);

// Option 1
//     Loop though result set with a foreach loop
foreach ($query as $message) {
    echo $message[0];
}

// Option 2
//     Loop through the result set with a while loop
while ($message = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $message["data"];
}
```

Comment: the while loop is what I'm using now thanks. also the tip on the oop made my code a little bit faster as i used to call the mysqli_connect on every function and repetitively. thanks